# Router/modem transparent bridge wrong IP address

Tags: networking, modem

this may be a weird question, let me know if more details will help. Will share beginning parts of IP addresses because I think that is all that is necessary to explain the issue...

I purchased a separate router than the one provided by Centurylink because I wanted to try out Wifi6 and some other features (went fairly low cost to start with the EDUP AX-1500)

Setup wasn't too hard... Telnet to modem/router from Centurylink (c1000z), extract the PPOE username and password, switch the modem/router to transparent bridge, connect it to the new modem, set that one up with the credentials, connected to internet and all devices connected just fine.

Weird thing is that the IP address seems... Wrong? I am used to the IP addresses from Centurylink before always being a 98.xxx.xxx IP address but now getting an 207.xxx.xxx IP address when looking at any "what is my IP" site.

Not so big a deal but when trying to access site I have hosted on my Raspberry pi it doesn't resolve to my machine (port forwarding is setup in router and everything). I still know the old IP address I last had earlier today (98.xxx.xxx) and if I use that from cellular network (do completely disconnected from modem/router) it still works (so that IP address is still leased to me for now) but using the current reported IP address (207.xxx.xxx) it doesn't resolve.

Tried trace route from my phone cellular network for both but couldn't tell anything wrong from that but I am not exactly a networking expert.

I if I were to guess... I don't think it makes a difference what third party router is being used... It is maybe a different behavior if you connect PPOE from a Centurylink modem/router combo versus a a standalone modem? I can't imagine why though because it should just be a well defined protocol either way... the fact that it still works with another IP address makes me suspect there is no issue with any actual routing... but maybe with reporting of what my current IP address is?

Any ideas?

Comment: We can only guess, but very, very likely the problem is not the model of device its that the MAC address has changed. In Ethernet type networks a lot can be ties  to a MAC address, including the IP address.  I've not posted thus as an answer though as it us unclear to me whybthus would matter with PPPoE.

Comment: @davidgo is right. The device initiating the PPPoE connection is the one obtaining an IP address via DHCP. Different device, different IP. They may even have rules that recognize their device MACs and treat them differently than others. The IP changing, to me, is insignificant. Look them both up and I’m sure you’ll find centurylink owns them. Have you talked to your ISP yet?